# Let (G, +) be a commutative group. Let a, b ∈ in G. Prove that K = {na + mb | n, m ∈ Z} is subgroup of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

So, a commutative group is an abelian group, I know what it's called... I'm having trouble understanding the proof for this. I know it's a theorem in which we use the Division Algorithm... the thing is that I'm not really sure how to begin the proof.

Comment: No, division algorithm has absolutely nothing to do with that. You have to show that a sum $(na+mb)+(n'a+m'b)$ and the inverse $-(na+mb)$ are again of the form $n''a+m''b$.

Comment: You should be able to do this directly from the definition of subgroup.  Check that $K \subset G$, and then check the group axioms.

Comment: Hint: it suffices to show that for $n,n',m,m' \in \Bbb Z$ that $(n-n')a + (m-m')b \in G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of $0_G = n (a-a)+m (b-b)=na+mb-na-mb=(n-n)a + (m-m)b \in K $ ($0\in\Bbb {Z} $) and for every $na+mb,n'a+m'b\in K $ we have $na+mb-(n'a+m'b)=(n-n')a+(m-m')b\in K $, because $n-n',m-m'\in \Bbb {Z} $, $K $ is a subgroup of $(G,+) $